# AWK binning every N lines

Tags: awk

I have data like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want to sum (bin) every N lines in this columns, but not like:

```
awk '{s+=$1}NR%2==0{print s;s=0}' file
```

For example, for 2 binnings I want to sum row 1+2, 2+3, 3+4, 4+5. So it would look like this:

```
3
5
7
9
```

For 3 binning like this:

```
6
9
12
```

Any ideas?

My real data looks like this:

```
2014-04-13 17:25:33.25  5.5
2014-04-13 17:25:53.25  27.5
2014-04-13 17:26:13.26  -3.5
2014-04-13 17:26:33.26  5.5
2014-04-13 17:26:53.26  22.5
2014-04-13 17:27:12.27  1.5
2014-04-13 17:27:32.27  26.5
2014-04-13 17:27:52.27  -14.5
2014-04-13 17:28:12.28  26.5
2014-04-13 17:28:32.28  0.5
2014-04-13 17:28:52.28  -14.5
2014-04-13 17:29:12.29  12.5
2014-04-13 17:29:32.29  9.5
```

The first two columns are the time with ~20 second steps, 3 lines is ~1 minute. So, for example, I would like to sum (bin) the 3rd column to get how much it changed overall in any given 30 minutes (90 lines), or 5 minutes (15 lines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this, for example:

```
awk -v bin=THE_NUMBER-1 '{a[NR]=$1}
       END {
            for (i=1; i<=NR-bin; i++)
               { 
                 for (j=0; j<=bin; j++) {c+=a[i+j]} 
                 print c; c=0
               }
           }' file
```

#### Explanation

- `-v bin=THE_NUMBER-1` give the value. We are using the number-1.
- `{a[NR]=$1}` store the value of each line.
- `END {}` execute at the end of the script.
- `{for (i=1; i<=NR-bin; i++)` loop through the line numbers, from the first to the last minus `bin`.
- `{ for (j=0; j<=bin; j++) {c+=a[i+j]}` loop through the sequence of lines affected, making the sum.
- `{print c; c=0}` print the result and reset the counter.

#### Test

For your given sample file `1 2 3...` it works like this:

```
$ awk -v bin=2 '{a[NR]=$1} END {for (i=1; i<=NR-bin; i++) { for (j=0; j<=bin; j++) {c+=a[i+j]} print c; c=0}}' file
6
9
12


$ awk -v bin=1 '{a[NR]=$1} END {for (i=1; i<=NR-bin; i++) { for (j=0; j<=bin; j++) {c+=a[i+j]} print c; c=0}}' file
3
5
7
9
```

In case you want to use the other file with dates, replace all `$1` with `$NF`, so that it gets the last column of the file as the number to check.

#### Test with your real file

```
$ awk -v bin=1 '{a[NR]=$NF} END {for (i=1; i<=NR-bin; i++) { for (j=0; j<=bin; j++) {c+=a[i+j]} printf "%.2f\n", c; c=0}}' a
33.00
24.00
2.00
28.00
24.00
28.00
12.00
12.00
27.00
-14.00
-2.00
22.00

$ awk -v bin=2 '{a[NR]=$NF} END {for (i=1; i<=NR-bin; i++) { for (j=0; j<=bin; j++) {c+=a[i+j]} printf "%.2f\n", c; c=0}}' a
29.50
29.50
24.50
29.50
50.50
13.50
38.50
12.50
12.50
-1.50
7.50

$ awk -v bin=3 '{a[NR]=$NF} END {for (i=1; i<=NR-bin; i++) { for (j=0; j<=bin; j++) {c+=a[i+j]} printf "%.2f\n", c; c=0}}' a
35.00
52.00
26.00
56.00
36.00
40.00
39.00
-2.00
25.00
8.00

$ awk -v bin=4 '{a[NR]=$NF} END {for (i=1; i<=NR-bin; i++) { for (j=0; j<=bin; j++) {c+=a[i+j]} printf "%.2f\n", c; c=0}}' a
57.50
53.50
52.50
41.50
62.50
40.50
24.50
10.50
34.50

$ awk -v bin=5 '{a[NR]=$NF} END {for (i=1; i<=NR-bin; i++) { for (j=0; j<=bin; j++) {c+=a[i+j]} printf "%.2f\n", c; c=0}}' a
59.00
80.00
38.00
68.00
63.00
26.00
37.00
20.00
```

Comment: thank you very much, i would up vote but don't have enought reputation yet.

Comment: @Padre, no problem I'll do it for you  ;) +1

Answer (score 2):

Like this in Awk

```
$ awk -v Bin=3 '{ tot += $3 } 0 == NR%Bin { print tot; tot = 0 }' data.txt
29.5
29.5
38.5
-1.5
```

But you are probably better off actually parsing the time stamp and using awk's `mktime()` to create *actual* time bins rather than your approximation. Unless, of course, you don't need that level of precision.

Using datetime functions:

```
awk -v Bin=1 '
    BEGIN { Step = Bin * 60; } # convert Bin in minutes to seconds
    function Output () {
        print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T -", StartTime), strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T", EndTime), Total; 
        Total = 0; 
        StartTime += Step;
        EndTime += Step; 
    }
    {
        Time = $1 OFS $2;
        sub(/\.[0-9]+$/, "", Time); 
        gsub(/[-:.]/, OFS, Time);
        Time = mktime(Time); 
    }
    1 == NR { 
        StartTime = Time;
        EndTime = StartTime + Step - 1;
    } 
    Time > EndTime { 
        Output()
    }
    {
        Total += $3; 
    } 
    END { Output() }
 '
2014-04-13 17:25:33 - 2014-04-13 17:26:32 29.5
2014-04-13 17:26:33 - 2014-04-13 17:27:32 56
2014-04-13 17:27:33 - 2014-04-13 17:28:32 12.5
2014-04-13 17:28:33 - 2014-04-13 17:29:32 7.5
```

Comment: thanks, this was really fast and simple! Could you explain the mktime() version too?