# Average every N lines and append the average as a new column, ideally at ceil(N/2) position

Tags: bash, awk, moving-average

I'm very new to awk I tried to modify the solution from [AWK binning every N lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104988/awk-binning-every-n-lines) but sadly I do not manage to correctly add the average as new column to my file.

In the first column I have date/time stamps, then in the next columns some data. I need the average of every N lines of one (later probably more) of the data columns. As a first solution I'd try to have the particular average value written next to the Nth row as a new column and just no entries for the lines in between (e.g. for N=100: from 0-99 there is no new output, but in the 100th row I get the average value of the last 100 values from the selected column)

My ultimate goal would be to have the calculated average values appended to every ceil(N/2) row. So that the average for N=100 would be appended at the 50th row.

As I only have limited knowledge and resources to solve this problem I might just run awk more than once and try to output my results to a temporary file first and then try to merge it.

Thank you very much!

PS: Actually it does not have to be awk only, I just figured it would probably be the most suitable solution.

Edit: My data looks like this:

```
-9,787440e+00;1,8;29,2;0,0033;0,0405;-0,0006;0,0102
-9,787360e+00;-1,90735e-07;28,8;0,0017;0,0033;0,00012;-0,00956
-9,787280e+00;-1,90735e-07;29,4;0,0017;0,0405;0,00036;0,0102
-9,787200e+00;1,8;29;0,0033;0,0093;0,00156;-0,00764
-9,787120e+00;8;29,4;0,0093;0,0405;0,00316;0,0102
-9,787040e+00;15,6;29;0,0167;0,0129;0,00332;-0,00636
```

In the first column I have relative time stamps and the other values are measured values. Now let's say for N=3 I need the average values of column 6 in a new column. The result should ideally look like this:

```
-9,787440e+00;1,8;29,2;0,0033;0,0405;-0,0006;0,0102
-9,787360e+00;-1,90735e-07;28,8;0,0017;0,0033;0,00012;-0,00956**;−0,00004**
-9,787280e+00;-1,90735e-07;29,4;0,0017;0,0405;0,00036;0,0102
-9,787200e+00;1,8;29;0,0033;0,0093;0,00156;-0,00764
-9,787120e+00;8;29,4;0,0093;0,0405;0,00316;0,0102**;0,00268**
-9,787040e+00;15,6;29;0,0167;0,0129;0,00332;-0,00636
```

I tried to mark the newly added entries bold **. So for N=3 the average of every 3 rows of column 6 should be added in the middle of every averaging window. ceil(3/2)=2 in this case on every second line after a new average is calculated.

Edit 2:
I managed to append the calculated average every N-th row - now I'd need to shift that back N/2 rows. Is this possible somehow with awk or some other bash tools? Overall it should be reasonably fast - I have to go through 65Mb of .csv files. Thanks a lot!

```
BEGIN { 
N=3
OFS=FS = ";";
}

{ 
    sum+=$1
}

{
    if (NR%N==0) {
        my_add_col=sum/N
        sum=0
        $(NF+1)=my_add_col
    }
}

{
    print $0
}
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output plus what you've tried so far so we can help you.

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you for your comment. I added some sample data. Sadly, I did not get a lot further than the thread I lined to. with {sum+=$1;};{if (NR%3==0) {my_add_col=sum/3; sum=0};}{print $0 my_add_col;} I did not even manage to get my value into a new column without a newline character. Furthermore, with this approach I have no idea how I could get the result on N/2 rows before the row when I calculate the average. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me assume;

- The decimal separator is a comma.
- The number of records is a multiple of N.

then would you please try the following:

```
LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 awk --use-lc-numeric -F";" -v N=3 '
    {
        sum += $6               # accumulate the value in the 6th field
        list[(NR-1)%N+1] = $0   # store current line in an array (to be displayed later)
    }
    NR%N==0 {                   # the line number is a multiple of N
        ave = sum / N
        ceil = int((N + 1) / 2) # the line to add the column of the average
        for (i = 1; i < ceil; i++) print list[i]
        print list[ceil] ";" ave
        for (i = ceil + 1; i <= N; i++) print list[i]

        sum = 0                 # initialize sum for the next iteration
        delete list             # initialize list of lines
    }
' data.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! :) At first I had problems with --use-lc-numeric etc., but works finally!